# Problems with the Iterator/Conditional Section of my Data Structure Manipulation Code - Ruby

Tags: ruby, data-manipulation, numeric

I am stuck on the iterator/conditional section of my code, it does not complete the iteration as expected.

The routine accepts a random non negative integer and must return a rearranged integer where the leftmost digit is the greatest digit of the input integer and the rightmost digit is the smallest.

The code is as follows:

```
 def descending_order(n)
    new = n.digits
    result=[]
    for i in new
      if i=new.max() then new.delete(i) && result.push(i)  
      end
    end
    return result.join().to_i 
  end
```

The sample input is as follows:

```
descending_order(6022563)
```

A sample of the erroneus result I get is as follows:

**descending_order(6022563) should equal 6653220 -  Expected: 6653220, instead got: 653**

Comment: @darkash covers most of the issues in a comment to my answer below, but just to reiterate and expand upon it:  The main issues with your code are that the delete method is deleting all instances of the number from your array and that nothing happens when the number is not the max value.  6 is max, gets added to result, and both 6’s are deleted from new; 0, 2, and 2 get ignored because they aren’t max; 5 is max, gets added to result, and gets deleted from new; 3 is max, gets added to result, and gets deleted from new.  new == [0, 2, 2]

Comment: By the way, there are other issues with your code as well.  i=new.max() seems like the wrong syntax.  I can only assume you meant to type i==new.max().  This wouldn’t have solved your problem but it’s another potential issue to consider.

Comment: Note: `new` is probably a bad name for a variable in Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to figure out what's going in your code, one of the best ways to do that, is to simply execute it step-by-step with pen and paper, keeping track of the current value of all variables in your code. So, let's do that.

However, before we start stepping through the code, let's first see if we can simplify it without changing how it works.

Firstly, the `return` is redundant. In Ruby, the return value of a block of code is the value of the last expression that was evaluated in that block. So, we can just remove the `return`.

Secondly, `for` … `in` is equivalent (not exactly, but the differences don't matter in this particular case) to `#each`, so your code could also be written like this:

```ruby
def descending_order(n)
  new = n.digits
  result = []

  new.each do |i|
    if i = new.max
      new.delete(i) && result.push(i)
    end
  end

  result.join.to_i 
end
```

Next, let's look at this bit:

```ruby
new.delete(i) && result.push(i)
```

This will delete all occurrences of `i` from `new`, and also test whether the return value of `new.delete(i)` is *trueish*. If and only if the value is *trueish*, `result.push(i)` will be executed.

However, `new.delete(i)` will only return a *falseish* value (namely `nil`) if the value `i` was not found in `new`. But, we just assigned `i` to be the maximum value in `new`, so we *know* it always exists and therefore, `new.delete(i)` will always return `i` and never `nil`. This means `result.push(i)` will always be executed and the conditional is not doing anything, we can just remove it:

```ruby
new.delete(i)
result.push(i)
```

Now, let's look at the conditional:

```ruby
if i = new.max
```

This assigns the maximum value of the `new` array to `i` and also tests whether that value is *trueish*. In other words, it is equivalent to

```ruby
i = new.max

if i
```

In Ruby, the only two values that are *falseish* are `false` and `nil`, so the only way this conditional can fail is if the maximum value of the `new` array is either `false` or `nil`. Since we know that we created the array from the digits of a number, we know that it only contains integers, not `nil` nor `false`. `Enumerable#max` also returns `nil` if the array is empty, so, the only way this can fail is if the array is empty. In other words, it is equivalent to

```ruby
i = new.max

if !new.empty?
```

or

```ruby
i = new.max

unless new.empty?
```

However, we also know that we are *in the middle of iterating over `new`*, so it cannot possibly be empty! If it were empty, the iteration would be executed 0 times, i.e. we would not be hitting this conditional at all.

Therefore, the conditional will always be true and can just be removed:

```ruby
def descending_order(n)
  new = n.digits
  result = []

  new.each do |i|
    i = new.max

    new.delete(i)
    result.push(i)
  end

  result.join.to_i 
end
```

Lastly, let's look at the iteration variable `i`. It will get assigned the current element of the iteration, but we *immediately* re-assign it on the first line of the block without ever looking at its value. So, it is actually not used as an iteration variable at all, it is simply a local variable and we can remove it from the block:

```ruby
def descending_order(n)
  new = n.digits
  result = []

  new.each do
    i = new.max

    new.delete(i)
    result.push(i)
  end

  result.join.to_i 
end
```

With this simplified code in place, we are now going to look at each step of each iteration of the loop separately.

We start off with the following (let's imagine we are just before the start of the first iteration):

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 6, 5, 2, 2, 0, 6]` |
| `result` | `[]` |
| `i` |  |

But, there is actually another, hidden, variable as well: the pointer to the current index. Remember, we are in the middle of iterating over `new` and `each` must internally somehow keep track of where we are. So, even though we don't know how `each` works internally, we can assume that it needs to somehow, somewhere, remember where we are. So, we have another piece of state to keep track of: the current index of the iteration.

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 6, 5, 2, 2, 0, 6]` |
| `result` | `[]` |
| `i` |  |
| index |  |

Alright, let's look at the first step of the first iteration, which is

```ruby
i = new.max
```

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 6, 5, 2, 2, 0, 6]` |
| `result` | `[]` |
| `i` | `6` |
| index | 0: [***→ 3 ←***, 6, 5, 2, 2, 0, 6] |

The next step is

```ruby
new.delete(i)
```

which deletes all occurrences of `i` from `new`, i.e. it deletes all occurrences of `6` from `[3, 6, 5, 2, 2, 0, 6]`. This leaves us with `[3, 5, 2, 2, 0]`, but what is also important is that `each` doesn't know what we are doing, that we are mutating the array. Therefore, the pointer will still stay at position `0`, it will not move.

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 5, 2, 2, 0]` |
| `result` | `[]` |
| `i` | `6` |
| index | 0: [***→ 3 ←***, 5, 2, 2, 0] |

The next step is

```ruby
result.push(i)
```

which appends `i` to the end of the `result` array:

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 5, 2, 2, 0]` |
| `result` | `[6]` |
| `i` | `6` |
| index | 0: [***→ 3 ←***, 5, 2, 2, 0] |

And that's it for the first iteration!

Let's look now at the second iteration. The first thing that is going to happen is that `each` internally increments its counter or moves its pointer, or however `each` is implemented internally. Again, we don't know how `each` is implemented internally, but logic dictates that it must somehow keep track of where we are in the iteration, and we can also assume that before the next iteration, it will somehow need to move this.

So, at the beginning of the iteration, the situation now looks like this:

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 5, 2, 2, 0]` |
| `result` | `[6]` |
| `i` |  |
| index | 1: [3, ***→ 5 ←***, 2, 2, 0] |

Alright, let's look at the first step of the second iteration:

```ruby
i = new.max
```

We again assign `i` to the maximum value of `new`, which is now `5`:

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 5, 2, 2, 0]` |
| `result` | `[6]` |
| `i` | `5` |
| index | 1: [3, ***→ 5 ←***, 2, 2, 0] |

Next step is

```ruby
new.delete(i)
```

which deletes all occurrences of `5` from `[3, 5, 2, 2, 0]`, which leaves us with `[3, 2, 2, 0]`. But remember what we also said above: `each` doesn't know what we are doing, that we are mutating the array. Therefore, the pointer will still stay at position `1`, it will not move. But the item that is at position `1` (which is the number `5`) will be deleted! That means, all elements after the `5`, i.e. all elements after index `1` now get shifted one index to the left, and that means the index pointer is still pointing at the *same index* but there is now a *different element* at that index:

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 2, 2, 0]` |
| `result` | `[6]` |
| `i` | `5` |
| index | 1: [3, ***→ 2 ←***, 2, 0] |

The root cause of this problem is that we are *mutating `new` at the same time that we are iterating over it*. This is a big no-no. You should *never* mutate a data structure while you are processing it. Or, at the very least, you need to be *very careful* that the mutations you do perform do not cause you to incorrectly process or skip parts of it.

Next step is

```ruby
result.push(i)
```

which means we push `5` to the end of `result`:

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 2, 2, 0]` |
| `result` | `[6, 5]` |
| `i` | `5` |
| index | 1: [3, ***→ 2 ←***, 2, 0] |

Alright, let's get to the next iteration: the pointer is again pushed forward to the next element, which leaves us with this picture:

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 2, 2, 0]` |
| `result` | `[6, 5]` |
| `i` |  |
| index | 2: [3, 2, ***→ 2 ←***, 0] |

First step:

```ruby
i = new.max
```

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[3, 2, 2, 0]` |
| `result` | `[6, 5]` |
| `i` | `3` |
| index | 2: [3, 2, ***→ 2 ←***, 0] |

Next step:

```ruby
new.delete(i)
```

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[2, 2, 0]` |
| `result` | `[6, 5]` |
| `i` | `3` |
| index | 2: [2, 2, ***→ 0 ←***] |

Next step:

```ruby
result.push(i)
```

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `new` | `[2, 2, 0]` |
| `result` | `[6, 5, 3]` |
| `i` | `3` |
| index | 2: [2, 2, ***→ 0 ←***] |

As you can see, the iteration pointer is now at the end of the array, so there will be no next iteration. Therefore, the final value of the result array is `[6, 5, 3]`, which we now join into a string and convert to an integer, so the final result is `653`.

Fundamentally, there are four problems with your code:

1. Presumably, the `if i = new.max` combined assignment / conditional which always clobbers the value of `i` is a typo, and you meant to write `if i == new.max`.
2. You are mutating the `new` array while at the same time you are iterating over it.
3. You are deleting every occurrence of `i` from `new`, but you are only adding one occurrence to the `result`.
4. Your logic is wrong: if the current element is not the maximum element, you skip over it and ignore it completely. But if the current element is not the maximum element, that *only* means that it should appear in the output *later*, not that it should *not appear at all*.

If you *only* fix #1, i.e. you replace `i = new.max` with `i == new.max` and change nothing else about your code, the result will be `6`. If you *only* fix #2, i.e. you replace `for i in new` with `for i in new.dup` (thus duplicating the `new` array and iterating over the copy so that mutating the `new` array itself does not influence the iteration), the result will be `65320`. If you fix *both* #1 and #2, the result will be `65`.

I encourage you to take pen and paper and trace all those three variants the same way we did above and fully understand what is going on.

Comment: Jorg, many thanks for your thorough answer...I've been totally schooled and I deeply appreciate it. I will study your feedback in detail and I really appreciate your time and patience to deal with my silly inquiry. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t address WHY you’re having a problem with your code, but here’s an alternative solution:

```
def descending_order(n)
  n.digits.sort.reverse.join.to_i
end
descending_order(6022563)
#=>  6653220
```

Comment: Thank Michael B, although this absolutely work. I would like to know what in my code is not working. Many thanks for your insight and suggestion.

Comment: @Panamaniac507 your code delete the number each time it is a max number in the array including the dupes, which is why each number in your result is unique. Another flaw in your code is it will do nothing if the number is not max, which explains why no number 2 or 0 in your result eventhough it got processed

You can try printing your code output in the loop to see how it goes

Comment: just a small comment on your solution...you missed the to_i after join...if ommited you are returning a string and not an integer.

Comment: My bad @Panamaniac507, I was tapping that out on my phone.  Correction made.